# Angular + Typescript: What ends up on the $scope?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, typescript, view-scope

I'm currently trying to integrate trNgGrid into my angular app where it's unfortunately not possible to bind a function from the controller to an `ng-click` on a row since it builds the table body itself. Instead, the documentation tells me that I have to `$watch` an array on the `$scope` for changes. I get the concept of the `$scope` but when using typescript and the `ControllerAs` syntax, it is rarely required to use it. So my question is: What ends up on the `$scope` and how do I watch it (the right way)?

Consider the following controller:

```
export class DummyViewModel {

    private iAmPrivate : number;
    public iAmPublic: number;

    constructor($scope : any) {
        $scope.amIOnTheScope = "??";
    }
}
```

So.. is `iAmPrivate` on the `$scope`? What about `iAmPublic`? Can I watch `iAmPublic` using `$scope.$watch("iAmPublic",...`. And if I access a public member of the controller from the view using `vm.iAmPublic`, where do I exactly bind to? The `$scope` or a secret controller narnia?

Comment: refer this link http://dotnetbyexample.blogspot.in/2014/07/angularjs-typescript-how-to-setup-watch.html

Answer (score 0):

> What ends up on the $scope and how do I watch it (the right way)?

if you have `DummyViewModel as vm` then `$scope.vm` is an instance of `DummyViewModel`

To watch something on the scope you would simply do :

```
$scope.$watch(()=>this.someMember,(val)=>{
     // Use new val
});
```

Of course there is the third `boolean` parameter to deep watch and also there is `$scope.$watchCollection` you can explore on your own.